# common encryption and decryption for all programming language

Tags: networking, encryption, cryptography

Hi I am working on an application which communicate with devices,sensors etc. In the application end we are using Java. But in device end it may be varied(ruby,python,embedded c etc).So I am searching which encryption and decryption algorithm supports by various programming language. Is there any algorithm like that, if it is kindly suggest that.

Comment: Do you want to encrypt data in transit or at rest? Do you need asymmetric encryption, or do you have a shared secret? For data in transit, use SSL/TLS.

Comment: we want encrypt data in transit.

Comment: Sounds like SSL to me. Then the peers can negotiate about what they both support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most commonly supported are AES (for symmetric encryption) and RSA (for public key encryption).

There are variants of each of these, though, in terms of padding, block mode, and so on, so you will still need to be careful to make sure you end up with something compatible.

Comment: Ok, I will try to analyze those algorithms.